# installing gcc-8-base on debian-12

Tags: gcc, debian, gcc8, debian-bookworm

I'm buidling a docker image using debian-12 and I need to install gcc-8-base on it:

```
FROM debian:12
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install build-essential gcc-8-base
```

I end up with an error that gcc-8-base is not found.

Is what am asking for correct or having gcc-8-base on debian-12 (bookworm not buster) is not doable?
if it is doable, I would be grateful if you could point out to any useful links.

Answer (score 0):

gcc-8 is no longer available on Debian 12; hopefully you can back up to 11 (buster).